# Reset Design With Visual Studio on Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am writing an ASP.NET webpage and accidentally I moved a control in the Design View and by trrying to put it back in position I completely destroyed the page layout.

I tried to delete the designer.cs file and Converting the page to a Web Application, cutting the code,saving pasting it and saving again, copying the code to a new Page. All with no result.

Is there an option like "Ignore the layout from the Design View" or similar?

Comment: My advice would be don't use the designer, just use the code editor.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Z - it does "Undo" as in any other MS package.

Comment: I was using the code editor, and then accidentally I moved one component by passing over it with the mouse. The Ctrl+Z did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to delete the Project, download the last version from Team Foundation Service and work from there.